# How can i see the content of a xml file in python

Tags: python

I'm struggling to find a way of seeing the content of a xml file. I have done a lot of searching and the only progress I am making is to keep running my code without any results

Comment: What do you mean by "seeing the content"? XML files are human readable. You can use any text processor (notepad, word, any browser...)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the BeautifulSoup package and use the lxml parser.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this url:
https://pymotw.com/2/xml/etree/ElementTree/parse.html

the relevant code:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

with open('example.xml', 'rt') as f:
    tree = ElementTree.parse(f)

print tree
```

This will print the XML file.
It's also good for parsing the file and search elements.

Comment: @ΝικολαοςΠεφανης, can you share what error you are getting?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/nick/PycharmProjects/untitled3/nick.py", line 5, in <module>
    tree = ElementTree.parse(f)
  File "C:\Anaconda3.6\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1196, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "C:\Anaconda3.6\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 597, in parse
    self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: undefined entity &ouml;: line 43, column 18

Comment: i should mention that the xml file is 2GB